# Javascript: Add multiple fields together and insert into Totals column on Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am new to javascript and am making a basic HTML timesheet form. I am simply trying to add the various hour types (Regular, overtime, sick, etc.) together and put that calculated value into a "Total hours" text box. Here is my function that I attempted (I am only using the 1 text box for now but would like advice on how to incorporate the others):

```
<script>
    function findTotal(hours, tot) {
        var hours = document.getElementsbyID('hours1').value;
        var tot = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(hours[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(hours[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    }
</script>
```

Here is the corresponding HTML form section:

```
<b>HOURS</b>
<table width="25%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <tr valign="Top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Regular</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal(hours)" id="hours1" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Overtime</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours2" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Sick</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours3" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Holiday</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours4" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Vacation</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours5" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Leave</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours6" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>Jury Duty</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" id="hours7" size="5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br /><b>TOTAL HOURS</b>
        </td>
        <td style="border-width : 0px;">
            <br />
            <input type="text" onblur="findTotal()" size="5" id="total">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

-Matt

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the same things many times, think about how you could do it **generically** with CSS (selector) or JavaScript (loop).

Cleaned up **HTML**:

```
<b>HOURS</b>

<table id="myTable" width="25%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Overtime</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Sick</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Holiday</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="hours4" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Vacation

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Leave</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Jury Duty</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>TOTAL HOURS</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="5" id="total" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is good pratice to **separate** JavaScript and HTML. 
If you work with HTML and JavaScript, it's good to understand how you could access, e.g here the **table**, **without** class (`getElementsByClassName`) and without id (`getElementById`).

Go through the table rows in the table. Therefore there are **rows** and **cells**:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = table.rows;
var rowsLength = rows.length // the number of all rows in the table
```

Example first row first cell:

```
var firstRowFirstCell = rows[0].cells[0];
```

Here, we go through the rows without the last row (total) `rowsLength - 1`. The `input` is in the second cell. Therefore we need `document.getElementsByTagName`

```
var input = rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

to add `addEventListener`:

```
input[0].addEventListener("blur", function() { ... });
```

for every input except total (the last one). Assign

```
function totalHours(containerID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(containerID);
    var rows = table.rows;
    var rowsLength = rows.length;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < (rowsLength - 1); i += 1) { // not the TOTAL input!
        var input = rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input");
        if(input[0].value !== "") { // no empty inputs
            total += parseInt(input[0].value); 
        }        
    }
    return total;
}
```

to them.

[Full example](http://jsfiddle.net/1cdbxf5y/2/)